# What's this matrix called?

Tags: matrices, notation, inner-products

In an inner product space, $v_1,\dotsc,v_n$ are linear independent iff the matrix $A_{ij} := \langle x_i | x_j \rangle$ is invertible. What's the name of this matrix??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

Comment: @HenryT.Horton Post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix $A$ given entrywise by $A_{ij} = \langle v_i, v_j \rangle$ is known as the [Gramian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of the set of vectors $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$.