# Prove that $1, x, x^2, \dots , x^n$ are linearly independent in $C[-1,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

As it states in the title, I'd like to prove that $1, x, x^2, \ldots , x^n$ are linearly independent in $C[-1,1]$.

Should I use an induction argument or integrate for $x^m$ and $x^n$ with cases $m=n$ and $m \neq n$?
The inner product is $$ \langle f,g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x)dx.$$ Do both methods work?

Comment: If you just prove for $x\to x^m$ and $x\to x^n$, you will only have proven that $x\to x^m$ and $x\to x^n$ are linearly independent.

Comment: A more general version of this question has been answered in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/364784/73324

Comment: @vadim123 Isn't easier than that?  We don't need to use the inner product at all here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose they aren't linearly independent in $[-1,1]$. Then $a_0+a_1x^1+\cdots+a_nx^n=0$ for some set of coefficients, where not all of them are zero. But an $n$ degree polynomial can have at most $n$ roots, but this one has infinitely many, a contradiction.

Comment: Infinitely many because it is identically zero on the interval (in fact on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: Yes, since every point in $[-1,1]$ is a root for this polynomial.

Answer (score 8):

*Hint*: Write down the definition of linear independence and use the fact that two polynomials are equal iff their coefficients are all the same.

Note that we don't need to use the inner product at all.  Linear independence is a property of a set in a *vector space*.

Comment: Does this still require an induction argument? Or just the observation that none of these polynomials have *any* coefficients in common and call it quits?

Comment: If you believe that "two polynomials are equal iff their coefficients are all the same", then there is certainly no induction necessary.

Comment: Isn't this preempting the result?

Comment: @MarkMcClure If you're using $\cdots$, then induction is needed.

Comment: Yes, isn't this in a sense assuming what the OP is trying to prove?

Comment: As I said, *If* you believe that "two polynomials are equal iff their coefficients are all the same", then you are just about done. That conclusion can be arrived at any number of ways. I see that @JLA, for example, has applied the fundamental theorem of algebra. I don't know what the OP's background is, which is one reason why I wrote this as a hint. When I assign this problem in an elementary linear algebra class, the first thing I want the students to do is clearly express what it means for the objects to be linearly independent. The justification for why it's true will certainly depend on

Comment: @MarkMcClure You don't need the fundamental theorem of algebra to show that a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots - using the Euclidean algorithm is enough

Answer (score 7):

Let $\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n$ $n+1$ real such that
$$\lambda_0+\lambda_1 x+\cdots +\lambda_n x^n=0\tag{1}$$
by derivative of $(1)$ succesively $k$ times $k=n,\ldots,1$ we find that $\lambda_n=0$ then $\lambda_{n-1}=0$ and so on hence we conclude

Comment: Hey, that doesn't use the inner product either!

Comment: Yes the inner product isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Set $f_n(x)=x^n$; you want to see that if
$$
\alpha_0f_0+\alpha_1f_1+\dots+\alpha_nf_n=0
$$
then $\alpha_0=\alpha_1=\dots=\alpha_n=0$. The hypothesis means that, in particular,
\begin{align}
&\alpha_0c_0^0+\alpha_0c_0^1+\dots+\alpha_nc_0^n=0\\
&\alpha_0c_1^0+\alpha_0c_1^1+\dots+\alpha_nc_1^n=0\\
&\dots\\
&\alpha_0c_n^0+\alpha_0c_n^1+\dots+\alpha_nc_n^n=0
\end{align}
where $c_0$, $c_1$, $\dots$, $c_n$ are pairwise distinct points in $[-1,1]$.
Therefore you have a homogeneous linear system with matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & c_0 & c_0^2 & \dots & c_0^n \\
1 & c_1 & c_1^2 & \dots & c_1^n \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
1 & c_n & c_n^2 & \dots & c_n^n
\end{bmatrix}\,.$$
This is a Vandermonde matrix, therefore invertible.

Answer (score 0):

A more verbal solution. Assume that one of the monomials, say $x^p$, linearly depend on the other monomials. Then it would be possible to write $x^p$ as linear combination of several $x^q$, where $q\ne p$. But this is clearly impossible and the contradiction proves that $x^p$, for any $p$, does not depend on the set of remaining $x^q$.

Comment: "Clearly impossible" doesn't prove it.